# Image not repeating properly

Tags: html, css, image, background, repeat

I'm trying to make a small image repeat as an overlay across the entire background video, but it just isn't working. I got it to this point and I've tried every multitude things I can think of. Any suggestions?
Code:

```css
    .overlay {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 0.7;
 background: #000 url(../media/overlay.png) repeat;
    }

    .content {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 720px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
    <div>
 <div class="overlay">
  <img src="/media/overlay.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <h1 class="content__heading"><img src="/media/logo.png" /></h1>
  <p class="content__teaser"> tba. </p>
  <a href="#" class="content__cta"> tba.</a>
 </div>
 <video id="my-video" class="video" muted loop>
  <source src="media/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `overlay` isn't big enough to show the repeating background.

try making the `overlay` full-page:

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You don't need to include the `<img>` in the HTML, since you already display the image using a CSS background.

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/448mdwyx/) (Note: I had to make `.overlay` `position: absolute` so that the overlay covers the whole height of the page)

Comment: When I get rid of the image tag though, the image is gone.

Comment: @Disloyalg Is the path `../media/overlay.png` in the CSS file correct (you can check in inspector)? Also, you might consider making `.overlay` `position:absolute`

Comment: Okay I got it to work now, but now the logo and such is up wayy too high.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you!